# Comparing arrays with -nan

Tags: arrays, swift, command-line, nan

I have two Double arrays with the equal amount of elements. Both of them contain numbers and some NaN values after trigonometric calculations.

I need to compare every element of the first array to every element of the second, find the greater number, and put it into a new third array. At the end, the third array should contain the same amount of elements as first or second array.

If two Nan are compared, I need to display a specific error message "terrible error" at that exact index. So I guess the third array should be String to be able to display both numbers and error messages. If a Double number is compared to NaN, the Double number should always be chosen as the greater.

How do I do all of that?

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation

var initValue = Double()
var finalValue = Double()
var stepValue = Double()

while true {
    print("Enter the starting number of the range")
    if let number = readLine(), Double(number) != nil {
        initValue = Double(number)!
        break
    } else {
        print("Enter the correct number!")
    }
}

while true {
    print("Enter the end value of the range")
    if let number = readLine(), Double(number) != nil, Double(number)! > initValue {
        finalValue = Double(number)!
        break
    } else {
        print("Enter the correct number, which is greater than starting number of the range!")
    }
}

while true {
    print("Enter delta")
    if let number = readLine(), Double(number) != nil {
        stepValue = Double(number)!
        break
    } else {
        print("Enter the correct number!")
    }
}

var trueArray = [Double]()
for number in stride(from: initValue, through: finalValue, by: stepValue) {
    trueArray.append(number)
}

func calcLn () -> [Double] {
    let calculatedArray = trueArray.map { log(1-46/sin($0)) }

    return calculatedArray
}

func calcTan () -> [String] {
    let calculatedArray = trueArray.map { (tan($0)/46) }

    return calculatedArray
}
```

Comment: what is some example input/output?

Comment: Example of input: 0, "enter", 5, "enter", 1. It gives us the following array: [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]. After calling for trigonometric functions, the output is going to look like: [-nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, 4.123612717137594, 3.891216438017379]
[0.0, 0.033856689666410915, -0.047500866592641716, -0.0030988378929190825, 0.025170027877164727, -0.07348945665753445], so there is no -nans among second function results, but they could be there!

Comment: @KezzaPalmer Please put those details into your question so people can see it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` to iterate over your 2 arrays concurrently, and then `map` to transform the pairs of elements into outputs, as you would like them. It's useful to switching on `(ln.isNaN, tan.isNaN)`, and use that to express the various cases and what their results should be.

Here's a rough start:

```
import Darwin

func promptForDouble(
    initialMessage: String,
    errorMessage: String,
    acceptanceCriteria isAcceptable: (Double) -> Bool = { _ in true }
) -> Double {
    print(initialMessage)

    while true {
        if let number = readLine().flatMap(Double.init), isAcceptable(number) {
            return number
        }

        print(errorMessage)
    }
}

let initValue = promptForDouble(
    initialMessage: "Enter the starting number of the range",
    errorMessage: "Enter the correct number!"
)
let finalValue = promptForDouble(
    initialMessage: "Enter the end value of the range",
    errorMessage: "Enter the correct number, which is greater than starting number of the range!",
    acceptanceCriteria: { initValue < $0 }
)
let stepValue = promptForDouble(
    initialMessage: "Enter delta",
    errorMessage: "Enter the correct number!"
)

// TODO: give these functions better names!
func calcLn(_ input: [Double]) -> [Double] {
    return input.map { log(1 - 46/sin($0)) }
}

func calcTan(_ input: [Double]) -> [Double] {
    return input.map { tan($0) / 46 }
}

func mergeResults(lns: [Double], tans: [Double]) -> [Double?] {
    return zip(lns, tans).map { ln, tan -> Double? in
        switch (ln.isNaN, tan.isNaN) {
            case ( true,  true): return nil // Return nil to express error. Don't introduce Strings yet.
            case (false,  true): return ln
            case ( true, false): return tan
            case (false, false): return max(ln, tan)
        }
    }
}

func printResults(_ a1: [Double], _ a2: [Double], _ a3: [Double?]) {
    for (a, (b, c)) in zip(a1, zip(a2, a3)) {
        let resultString = c.map(String.init) ?? "terrible error" // Note: Strings are only introduced at the UI/presentation layer
        print("ln: \(a),\ttan: \(b),\tresult: \(resultString)") 
    }
}


// TODO: give these arrays better names!

let inputs = Array(stride(from: initValue, through: finalValue, by: stepValue))

let array1 = calcLn(inputs)
let array2 = calcTan(inputs)
let array3 = mergeResults(lns: array1, tans: array2)

printResults(array1, array2, array3)
```

Comment: Alexander, I have marked your question as accepted, thank you once again! Could you also help me with two another things? I'm not sure how to add if-statements here: I need to display errors when tan "doesn't exist" (for example, if input is equal to 3pi/2, it gives me an infinity) and display my results as a table: print only current input step and result of finding the greater number

Comment: "when tan "doesn't exist" (for example, if input is equal to 3pi/2, it gives me an infinity)" How exactly do you want to handle such values?

Comment: If log is nan, and tan doesn't exist (gives infinity), I need to display "terrible error" at that index

Comment: @KezzaPalmer So then why don't you update the `mergeResults` function to do that?

Comment: The problem is, I'm not sure how to do it :(

Comment: @KezzaPalmer Then you probably don't understand how this code works, do you?

Comment: Not exactly, to be honest

Comment: @KezzaPalmer I explicitly told me that you can ask my any questions you have about this. You won't learn anything by just copy pasting code from the internet without spending the time to understand it. What parts do you understand? What's the first thing you don't understand?